# How to loop over to get content of mouse hover elements using Python/selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a website which I'm using Selenium to extract information from mouse hover box that shows up to display relevant information for each review. I was able to get the first one correct and no matter how I tried I have trouble loop over the page to get information from all. Can Anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong. Here is my code.

````
from lxml import html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="YOUR PATH")
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

driver.get("https://www.depositaccounts.com/banks/reviews/chase-manhattan-bank.html")

#find all
data= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'bankReviewContainer')]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]")

for i in data:
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(i).perform()
        time.sleep(2)
        #print content of each box
        hover_data=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='popover fade right in']").get_attribute("innerHTML")
        print ( hover_data)

driver.quit()```
````

Comment: Your `data` is not a list, but a single webElement. Didi you mean `data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(...)`?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry for the confusion. it should be data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(...).

Comment: P.S. Also it'd be better to define your `data` as `driver.find_elements_by_class_name('stars1')`.

Comment: After changing "element" to "elements" it works fine until 3rd mouse hover box . apperantly there is no box in 4th comment and loop stops and gives an error. Seems like I have to find a way to deal with missing mouse hover box at this point. Frankly speaking I did not know there is a difference using find_elements_by_xpath and find_element_by_xpath. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `find_elements_by_xpath` instead of `find_element`.

Try this code:

```
#find all
data= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'bankReviewContainer')]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]")

for i in data:
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(i).perform()
        time.sleep(2)
        #print content of each box
        hover_data=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='popover fade right in']").get_attribute("innerHTML")
        print(hover_data)
```